# Disprove statement about differentiable function

Tags: limits, derivatives

I need to disprove the following statement, about a differentiable function $f(x)$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty \implies\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty$$

I can't find a counter example in order to disprove it.

Comment: Hint:  In your case, it's easy to see that $f'(x)$ can't approach some finite limit, so try to construct an example where $f'(x)$ is negative for arbitrarily large values...of course it must also be positive for arbitrarily large values so the limit of $f'(x)$ won't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I propose
$$f(x)=x^2+\sin(e^x)$$
Then $$\frac{f(x)}{x}\sim x \to \infty$$
And
$$f'(x)=2x+e^x\cos(e^x)$$
has no limit, it keeps oscillating between large positive values and large negative values.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = x^2(2+ \sin(x))$$

[image: Image of function f(x) = x^2(2+ \sin(x))]

Or any other function whose overall shape is that of $x^p, p>1,$ and that oscillates as $x$ increases.